# What algorithms perform better with adjacency matrix as compared to lists?

Tags: data-structures, graph-algorithm

Are there any algorithms for which adjacency matrices outperform adjacency lists? What about vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of Running Time, Adjacency Matrix would almost always outperform lists. The List implementation would use less memory(proportional to number of edges) to store the Graph.

So if memory does matter(it surely would with sparse Graphs with large number of nodes), use lists. If run time matters, and the Graph is likely to be dense, use Adjacency Matrix.

Comment: hi, thanks.  Is there some algo where list does better than matrix in terms of run time? [since you said *almost*]

Comment: You take the memory hit only if you use a dense matrix (i.e. 2D array). If you use a sparse matrix then you get to keep the space savings as well, but you have to be careful about how the matrix is traversed. But that's true for the 2D array as well due to the effects of caching.

Comment: @Karthick, when using a dense matrix an algorithm to find the degree of a vertex would be faster with lists. The entire matrix column/row has to be traversed, while the list only traverses existing edges. Again, a sparse matrix solves that problem.

Comment: @Karthick: It would matter during the initialization of the matrix. Also, For algorithms such as Dijkstra, where traversing over the edge is performed, if you used Matrix instead, you would be going over redundant entries of non existent edges.

Comment: It depends on if the graph is a dense or sparse.